# How to convert a string parameter to an attribute of variable TypeScript Angular

Tags: angular, string, typescript, parameters

I have these 2 methods :

```
changeStartTime(event, id) {
    if (event.hour >= 10 && event.minute >= 10) {
      this.priceRules[id-1].startTime = event.hour+":"+event.minute;
    }
    else if (event.hour >= 10 && event.minute < 10) {
      this.priceRules[id-1].startTime = event.hour+":0"+event.minute;
    }
    else {
      this.priceRules[id-1].startTime = "0"+event.hour+":0"+event.minute;
    }
  }

  changeEndTime(event, id) {
    if (event.hour >= 10 && event.minute >= 10) {
      this.priceRules[id-1].endTime = event.hour+":"+event.minute;
    }
    else if (event.hour >= 10 && event.minute < 10) {
      this.priceRules[id-1].endTime = event.hour+":0"+event.minute;
    }
    else {
      this.priceRules[id-1].endTime = "0"+event.hour+":0"+event.minute;
    }
  }
```

As you can see, they are very very similar, the only thing that changes is `startTime` and `endTime`. It's a bad manner of a developer, so what I want is only one method with a third parameter ( maybe a string ? ) but i don't know how to do that. Thank you

Comment: this.priceRules[id-1]["typeTime"] ? did you try, you can this object notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow this syntax:

```
this.priceRules[id-1]['startTime']
```

Instead of this:

```
this.priceRules[id-1].startTime
```

i.e.

Here you can pass 'startTime' and 'endTime' as an argument of changeTime function

```
changeTime(event, id, key) {
    if (event.hour >= 10 && event.minute >= 10) {
      this.priceRules[id-1][key] = event.hour+":"+event.minute;
    }
    else if (event.hour >= 10 && event.minute < 10) {
      this.priceRules[id-1][key] = event.hour+":0"+event.minute;
    }
    else {
      this.priceRules[id-1][key] = "0"+event.hour+":0"+event.minute;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that this maybe will fix your problem, but not sure because i didn't see your *priceRules* structure.

```
changeTime(event, id, type) {
  if (event.hour >= 10 && event.minute >= 10) {
    this.priceRules[id-1][type] = event.hour+":"+event.minute;
  }
  else if (event.hour >= 10 && event.minute < 10) {
    this.priceRules[id-1][type] = event.hour+":0"+event.minute;
  }
  else {
    this.priceRules[id-1][type] = "0"+event.hour+":0"+event.minute;
  }
}
```

Where *'type'* must be *'startTime'* or *'endTime'*.